How to triagulate multiple sound locations
Other people posed the question of how to triangulate sound from multiple locations.
Approximate (but as accurate as it can) location of sound
Sound Triangulation
My question is how to seperate multiple interfering sound sources.
Specifically, if we assume sound amplitude is inversely proportional to the sound source, how can m sound locations be identified from n sound recordings?
Assume the following:
Each sound source (ss1, ss2 … ssj … ssm) is defined by a unique pair of x and y coordinates, and a function ssjf with a range in the real numbers, representing pressure values, and a domain in the real values, representing time. It is known that an integral over these values yields a finite value.
Each sound recording (sr1, sr2 … srk … srn) is also defined by a unique pair of x and y coordinates, and a function srkf with a range in the real numbers, representing pressure values, and a domain in the real values, representing time.
It is known that:
srkf(t) = ss1f(t-d1k)/d1k + ss2f(t-d2k)/d2k + … ssif(t-djk)/djk + … ssmf(t-dmk)/dmk
where djk is the distance between ssj and srk in the (x,y) coordinate plane.
For what values of m and n is there a unique set of sound source locations and pressure functions?
I calculate the following:
The sound pressure values of each source are equivalent to frequencies produced by each source. The phase values of these frequencies get shifted depending on distance to the source, and the amplitudes get reduced.
Now this is equal to the set of equations for all frequencies f in the real numbers and for each kth recording and jth sound source.
R(k,f) = sumOverJ(sj,f * e^(2PIif*dist(sj,rk))/dist(sj,rk))
Which breaks down into the following real valued equations:
Rreal(k,f) = sumOverJ(sreal(j,f) * cos(2PIf*dist(sj,rk)) /dist(sj,rk)) – SumOverJ(simag(j,f) * sin(2PIf * dist(sj,rk)) /dist(sj,rk))
Rimag(k,f)  = sumOverJ(sreal(j,f) * sin(2PIf* dist(sj,rk)) / dist(sj,rk)) + SumOverJ(simag(j,f) * cos(2PIf * dist(sj,rk)) / dist(sj,rk))
If the distances are known, this becomes a linear equation, which may or not have a solution, but requires having the number of recordings at least as high as the number of sources to bring the degrees of freedom down to zero.
Now, the positions of the sound sources each contribute 2 degrees of freedom, and each additional sound recording frequency takes away 2 degrees of freedom.
This would mean that, generally speaking (in the same way an n-variable, n-equation linear system is generally solvable) when there are 2 or more sound sources, it would take 2m sound recordings using a single frequency to determine the amplitudes, phases, and locations of m sound sources, and with enough sound frequencies m+1 sound recordings can determine the locations of m sound locations.
However, this doesn’t account for how the nonlinear system of equations operates. So, is this accurate, or are more recordings needed?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

As the Bot says, could you clarify your question? What is the setup? What measurements are available? Are the sounds emitted simultaneously? Is the situation with $m$ sound sources different from just solving for one source $m$ times?

Basically you make a model of $m$ sources.  If you control the sources, you can give each one its own frequency, then pick that frequency out of what you receive, and locate that source independent of all the others.  If you don't control them but know what each one is playing you can analyze the sound you hear at each receiver and pick out each source by solving the superposition.  I think if you can't pick one source out of the received sound you don't have much hope.
